# isn´t a known property when i try to build with **Ionic build android --prod**

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i tried to build my project with **Ionic build android --prod** but i got always the following error: 
[image]

The `<events-list>`component is declared in EventslistModule:

```
   declarations: [
       EventsListComponent,
       NewestEventsComponent
   ],
   imports: [IonicModule, LoaderModule],
   exports: [
       EventsListComponent,
       NewestEventsComponent,
   ],
   schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class EventsListModule {}
```

and here are the properties in events-list.ts :

```
@Input() set eventChange(filteredEvents){
    this.filteredEvents = filteredEvents;

    if(this.initial == true){
        this.loadData();
    }
  };

  @Input() created:boolean = false;
  @Input() search:boolean = false;
  @Input() id:string;
  @Input() answered:boolean = false;
  @Input() fromCalender:boolean = true;
  @Input() status:number = 4;
  @Input() showMessages = true;
```

---

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.4 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, browser 5.0.3, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 30 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.8 (update available: 0.3.0)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/leonardoprivat/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 11.0 Build version 11A420a
```

When i build the project without **--prod** then it works fine.

Any Idea how i can solve this problem?

Comment: You should be more specific about version of ionic/angular etc you are using.

Comment: okay i updated it

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz and share?